# How to hook PHP PDO::query() up?

Tags: php, pdo, extends

I want to write an extension to PDO class by hooking a PDO::query() method. And I want to pass all the arguments correctly. So I check for the PDO::query() argument list and here is what I find:

```
public PDOStatement PDO::query (string $statement)

public PDOStatement PDO::query(string $statement, int $PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, int $colno)

public PDOStatement PDO::query(string $statement, int $PDO::FETCH_CLASS, string $classname, array $ctorargs)

public PDOStatement PDO::query(string $statement, int $PDO::FETCH_INTO, object $object)
```

This functions does not have one single definition... it has four definitions instead and the last three are not even documented! So how do I properly hook this method up? I want to keep this method fully functional. Don't want to lose anything it provides.

Comment: If you don't understand the documentation I don't think you should be trying to extending the class.